# watir webdriver error resolving host

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

Just have a simple script to automate a firefox browser:
Just have a simple script to automate a firefox browser:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
# Initialize watir firefox browser
$browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff , :profile => 'default'
```

Leads to the following error which I havent been able to figure out. Is there a TCP port that is blocked or something?.I am using my office pc btw , the code works fine on my home pc.

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: No such
host is known.  (SocketError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `block in connect'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `connect'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:744:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:76:in `response_for'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:38:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:598:in `raw_execute'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:92:in `create_session'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:68:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/firefox/bridge.rb:28:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:31:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:31:in `for'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/s
elenium/webdriver.rb:65:in `for'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir
-webdriver/browser.rb:35:in `initialize'
        from sic_class.rb:8:in `new'
        from sic_class.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

There is no proxy, I am using windows 7, watir webdriver 0.6.1 and firefox 13.01

Comment: Have you found a fix for this?  I've just run into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to install gems then the http_proxy environment variable must be set in ur PATH. But this causes the above problem with watir-webdriver, it worked for me after removing the http_proxy variable. It then uses the proxy settings in browser.